# Ionic / Angular class design pattern

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Says I am building a banking app that request **bankAccountRawInput** from a remote service. The app then calculate the *amountAfterInterest* and instantiate a new class **bankAccount** from the raw data.

Raw Data Interface

```
interface bankAccountRawInput {
    public amount : number;
    public interestRate : number;
}
```

Data Provider Class

```
@Injectable()
export class bankAccount {
  public amount : number;
  public interestRate : number;
  public amountAfterInterest : number

  constructor(bankAccountRawInput : bankAccountRawInput) {
    this.amountAfterInterest = this.amount * (1 + this.interestRate)
  }
}
```

When a view needs to consume the data, it does this

```
getBankAccount() {
    this.bankAccountRawInput = callRemoteService.get();
    this.bankAccount = new BankAccount(bankAccountRawInput);
}
```

and says the user can choose the interest rate, so every time the input changes I recreate a new class.

```
updateBankAccount(newValue) {
    this.bankAccountRawInput.interestRate = newValue;
    this.bankAccount = new BankAccount(bankAccountRawInput);
}
```

I am concern whether it is a good idea to always use new keyword to create classes and update. Is there a better pattern for example by creating an update method to bankAccount to update changes and recalculate value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your pattern as shown below.

**Note:** You don't need to use `public`.By default, it is `public`. Please see the `inline comments` for more info. You need to do necessary `imports` inside the `components`.

**bankAccountRawInput.ts**

```
interface bankAccountRawInput {
    amount : number;
    interestRate : number;
}
```

**bankAccount.ts (provider)**

```
@Injectable()
export class BankAccount implements bankAccountRawInput {//implements interface like this.
  amount : number;
  interestRate : number;
  amountAfterInterest : number

  constructor() {//no need to inject interface here now

    this.amountAfterInterest = this.amount * (1 + this.interestRate)

  }

  bankMethod() : void {
   console.log("Hi");
  }
}
```

**page.ts**

```
export class MyPage{

   constructor(public bankAccount : BankAccount ){//inject your service here
      }

   getBankAccount() {
       this.bankAccount.bankMethod();//no need to use `new` keyword here.Angular does it on behalf of us when we injected in the constructor.
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you set the values from rawInput into BankAccount class and calculate / update values?

Comment: Can you show the code of this `callRemoteService.get()`? You can put that on your original question.